# Regex pattern to replace to first segments of file path

Tags: c#, regex, regexp-replace

I have such types of file paths:

1. `\\server\folder\folder1\folder3\someFile.txt`,
2. `\\otherServer\folder123\folder1\folder3\someFile.txt`
3. `\\serv\fold\folder3\folder4\someFile.txt`

I need to remove the first two segments of this path to make them as follows:

1. `folder1\folder3\someFile.txt`,
2. `folder1\folder3\someFile.txt`
3. `folder3\folder4\someFile.txt`

I'm doing it with c# and `Regex.Replace` but need a pattern.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, that you work files' *paths*, and that's why I suggest using `Path` not `Regex`:

```
using System.IO;

...

string source = @"\\serv\fold\folder3\folder4\someFile.txt";

var result = Path.IsPathRooted(source)
  ? source.Substring(Path.GetPathRoot(source).Length + 1)
  : source;
```

If you insist on regular expressions then

```
string result = Regex.Replace(source, @"^\\\\[^\\]+\\[^\\]+\\", "");
```

Comment: Thanks, it is actually what I looking for

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regular expression pattern to remove the first two segments:
^\\[^\\]+\\[^\\]+\\

you can use Regex.Replace in C#
example:

```
string input = "\\\\server\\folder\\folder1\\folder3\\filename.txt";
string pattern = "^\\\\[^\\\\]+\\\\[^\\\\]+\\\\";
string replacement = "";
```

var result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacement);

```
 output:
folder1\folder3\filename.txt
```